# Cross-message state in Mule ESB

Tags: mule

I need to create an "accumulator" service to be used by Mule ESB applications.

This service will hold inbound messages until a certain number are received and then package those messages into a single outbound message.

This is the first time I've needed to write an ESB application that needs to maintain state (the collection of previously received messages) across inbound messages and I'm not quite sure how to get started.

I think what I need is a place to hang a reference to a data structure that holds my lists of inbound messages, but I'm not sure.

What's the best (most productive, most consistent with ESB best-practices) mechanism for managing "application-level" (i.e. cross-message) state data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this scenario you need to use the aggregator pattern. Please follow the below link .
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/32X/Message+Splitting+and+Aggregation